# Django: Password check returning false in view when it should return true

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

As part of form validation, the password and password2 are compared. This is part of a simplified ajax request system for an extremely small site returning small amounts of data (so i don't use JSON). The idea/objective/summery of the program is that it tries to log in the user. If the user does not exist, it asks the client side to load/reveal the form for new users (just an added password2 field and asks for a pen name).  Here is the file, I've marked the sport where the program freezes with `#*********`

Forms.py (error is not here):

```
class new_user(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    password2 = forms.PasswordInput()
    pen_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Views.py, where the error is:

```
def user_log_in(request):
    #add stuff for ajax request
    user_pass = log_in(request.POST)
    er = []
    if user_pass.is_valid():
        print "valid"
        cleaned_info = user_pass.cleaned_data
        user_object = User.objects.filter(email = cleaned_info['username'])
        if user_object.exists():
            logged_in_user = auth.authenticate(username=cleaned_info['username'], auth_password=cleaned_info['password'])
            #add in is_active
            if logged_in_user is not None:
                auth.login(request, logged_in_user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
            else:
                er.append("Incorrect Password")
        else:
            new_user_pass = new_user(request.POST)
            if new_user_pass.is_valid():
                cleaned_info_new = new_user_pass.cleaned_data
                print "check points"
                if cleaned_info_new['password'] == cleaned_info_new['password2']: #********
                    print "clean"
                    new_user_query = creat_user(
                        username=cleaned_info_new['username'],
                        password=cleaned_info_new['password'],
                        email=cleaned_info_new['username']
                    )
                    new_user_query.save()
                    msg = ""
                    try:
                        send_mail("Activate", msg,  'mrgnippy@gmail.com',
                            [cleaned_info['username']], fail_silently=False)
                    except:
                        er.append("Error Sending Email")
                else:
                    er.append('Passwords are not the same')
            elif "TN" in request.POST:
                print "TN"
                for e in new_user_pass.errors:
                    er.append(e)
            #elif to check for is_active
            else:
                print "n_usr"
                return HttpResponse('n_usr')
    else:
        for e in user_pass.errors:
            er.append(e)
        for e in er:
            print"-"
            print e
            print"-"
    return HttpResponse('SOS')
```

The django debug page says the following:

```
KeyError at /ajax/login 'password' Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/login Django Version: 1.4 Python Executable:
```

The post variable stuff in the error is this (I blanked out my email and):

```
GET: No GET data POST: username = u'********@aol.com' TN = u'TN' password2 = u'test' password = u'test' pen_name = u'testing123' FILES: No FILES data
```

Just in case the problem is here, I've included the javascript file.

```
n_usr = false;
function log_in () {
    if(!$('#pass_enter').hasClass('#usr_enter')){
        password = $('#pass_enter').val();
    }else{
        password = '';
    }
    if(!$('#usr_enter').hasClass('blur_field')){
        username = $('#usr_enter').val();
    }else{
        username = '';
    }
    alert(username);

    if(!n_usr){
        $.post('/ajax/login',{password: password, username: username}, function(data) {
            if(data == "n_usr"){
                $('#new_user_entry').show('slow');
                n_usr = true;
            }
            else {

            }

        })
    }else {
        if (!$('#pass_re_enter').hasClass('blur_field')){
                password2 = $('#pass_re_enter').val();
        }else {
                password2 = '';
        }
        if (!$('#pass_re_enter').hasClass('blur_field')){
            penname = $('#pen_enter').val();
        }else {
            penname = '';
        }
            $.post('/ajax/login', {password: password, password2: password2, username: username, pen_name: penname, TN: "TN"}, function(data) {
                if(data == "e_act"){

                } else {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you declare `new_user` form?

Comment: Why not django's default auth?

Comment: @Justanotherdunce I do, it's just that this form not only logs in the user, but if the user is not registered, it asks for additional information on the user side (JQuery reveals rest of form if Django returns n_usr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that I used the wrong fields in the forms.py file. Problem solved.